# Apache Tomcat Exception in Console on Startup

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using tomcat to run a web application.  Without any projects added to my Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost, I start the server and an exception is being thrown.  It says there isn't a mapping for class sun.awt.AppContext  I'm using jre6 as my runtime.  I have my JAVA_HOME environmental variation set to the jre6 folder and I have Eclipse set to the same one.  Do you know why I am getting this exception and how to resolve?

Here is my stack trace:

```
Nov 1, 2011 5:21:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:\oracle\Ora11g\BIN\;C:\Program Files\Serena\Dimensions 2009 R1\CM\prog;C:\Program Files\Serena\Dimensions 2009 R1\CM\prog\Microsoft.VC80.MFC;C:\Program Files\Serena\Dimensions 2009 R1\CM\prog\Microsoft.VC80.CRT;C:\Program Files\Serena\Dimensions 2009 R1\CM\prog\Microsoft.VC80.ATL;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Common Files\OTG;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\IBM\Personal Communications\;C:\Program Files\IBM\Trace Facility\;C:\Program Files\HP\QuickTest Professional\bin;c:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;c:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;c:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\Program Files\Eclipse 3.7\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\HP\QuickTest Professional\bin
    Letting agent QTJA do the transformation
    Letting agent QTOR do the transformation
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: No mapping for class sun.awt.AppContext
        at com.mercury.bcel.TransformerXmlFile$MappingLocator.setMapping(TransformerXmlFile.java:96)
        at com.mercury.bcel.TransformerFactory.createTransformer(TransformerFactory.java:56)
        at com.mercury.bcel.TransformerMainImpl.transform(TransformerMainImpl.java:33)
        at com.mercury.bcel.TransformerMain.transform(TransformerMain.java:35)
        at com.mercury.javashared.transform.TransformersChain.transform(TransformersChain.java:32)
        at com.mercury.javashared.transform.CommunicationThread.processTransformRequest(CommunicationThread.java:61)
        at com.mercury.javashared.transform.CommunicationThread.run(CommunicationThread.java:38)
```

Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Hi, what's your OS, have you tried to re-install Tomcat?

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) Check for CLASSPATH environment variable and unset it, if it exists. 2) Check for Xerces dependency of your App. 3) Tell us more about the libraries in tomcat/lib and within your webapp if any.

Comment: @hovanessyan ,Windows XP No I haven't reinstalled I have the zip file version of Tomcat.  Also, I think it's more of an issue with variable pathing.

Comment: @micfra There are locations set to my CLASSPATH, but my system variables are locked.  My app is not Xerces dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is HP QuickTest.

HP QuickTest sets up JVM options which modify the java bootclasspath - nasty.

I'm not sure exactly how it works, but I'm guessing that it sets an environment variable JAVA_OPTS (which is picked up by Tomcat's startup scripts)

3 options (first is definite, second & third are based on my guess above):

1. Try uninstalling HP QuickTest
2. Open up bin\catalina.bat inside your Tomcat installation, and try resetting JAVA_OPTS at the start of the script.

Something like this:

```
   echo "Current JAVA_OPTS (resetting to ''):"
   echo %JAVA_OPTS%
   set JAVA_OPTS=""
```

3: Or, try setting JAVA_OPTS variable (to empty string) in your Eclipse server startup dialog

Comment: I'm on a work computer and I didn't even know I had HP QuickTest installed. I can't uninstall it.  I tried to reset the JAVA_OPTS variable, but I discovered that my system variables are locked.  So, if I'm not able to change _JAVA_OPTIONS or CLASSPATH and if I can't uninstall HP QT is there an alternative?

Comment: Hi Frogger, did you try option 2 (*tomcat*\bin\catalinat.bat)? You should be able to set variables inside a .bat script (or command prompt), so try editing this). If you can't edit this file, just download another copy of Tomcat. Tomcat doesn't need to be 'installed', just unzip the zip distribution somewhere that you have write permissions, and edit catalina.bat

Comment: Yeah, I did try that.  I set the variable _JAVA_OPTIONS="", and then restarted the server and it still had the same exception.  Also, when I close catalina.bat the variable gets automatically reset to the _JAVA_OPTIONS that's locked.  What about option 3, how do I change the variable in the server startup dialog?

Comment: Go to Menu: Run > Run Configurations ..., and then pick your launcher on the left (you may need to crreate a new launcher under Apache Tomcat). Then you should see an Environment tab, where you can add Environment variables...

Comment: Ok, I did that.  Now it says Cannot create Virtual Machine JVM since I set the _JAVA_OPTIONS to "".

Comment: Curious. Well, at least you're on the right path.. It could be an issue with the JVM installation(?) If I could see all your environment variables and details about the JVM, it would help. Without that, I can only guess Tomcat might not have enough RAM allowance. Try  `_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx=512m"` ... is this JVM part of the HPQT installation? if so, try installing another jvm. (at this point it's something you should discuss with your IT support team, rather than me, as I can't see your system)

Comment: My _JAVA_OPTIONS in system variables looks like:                         -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar.  Perhaps one of these is causing the problem?  I'll try it will just the jvm hook and bootclasspath.

Comment: Also, I have jdk 1.5 set to JAVA_HOME, it's weird that if I make that _JAVA_OPTIONS blank it can't find my JVM.  Isn't _JAVA_OPTIONS just additional commands that add on when java is called?

Comment: Yeah it's just options passed into the Java runtime. I'm not really familiar with it, nor this quirky HP Java installation, but you might want to reproduce this option, leaving out the path to jasmine.jar,  i.e. `;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUIC‌​KT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar`. That is the most likely cause of the issue.

Comment: Hmm I tried that and now in my console it says "Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library jvmhook on the library path, with error: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system".. strange

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same issue, but my Apache Tomcat loaded through Cargo Container wrapper.
So I removed these 2 env. variable to fix the issue

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS         -agentlib:jvmhook
_classload_hook           jvmhook
```